# Is there any way to present the default iOS editing view from the photos app without using an image picker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, photosframework

Is there any way to present the default iOS editing view from the photos app (see image below) without using an image picker (just on a button tap)?

[image: default iOS photos app editing controller]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to present the default iOS editing view from the
>   photos app without using an image picker?

The answer is no, because you cannot access the code of other apps, and the iOS image editing view is not an element which is built-in and provided to developers by Apple. You can just create your custom view, or use one amongst a lot of online extensions.